# Appending variable to end of file on a newline in Python

Tags: python, file, append

I am trying to append the data from a variable to the end of a file Python - **on a new line**. I have used this method: `(variable+"/n")` but in the file it has all of the file data on one line including the `/n` symbol.

My code *(this is an example! So it makes sense in exactly what I want to be answered)*:

```
list = ["apple","pear","strawberry"]
f = open("test.txt","a")
for x in list:
    f.write(x+"/n")
    print(x)
f.close()
```

Output in `test.txt`:

```
apple/npear/nstrawberry/n
```

What can I do so that the output looks like this:

```
apple
pear
strawberry
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: `"/n" != "\n"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace forward-slash (/) with a backslash ().

Code:

```
list = ["apple","pear","strawberry"]
f = open("test.txt","a")
for x in list:
    f.write(x+"\n")
    print(x)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using \n instead of /n on line 5.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works correctly

```
list = ["apple","pear","strawberry"]
    f = open("test.txt","a")
    for x in list:
      f.write(x)
      print(x, end='/n')
    f.close()
```

Output:

```
apple/npear/nstrawberry/n
```